# Dynamic transition for statesman gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.2, My application needs a finite state machine whereas, the finite state transition flow will be configured by the users and stored in db. How can I fetch the dynamic state transition from db and set it for statesman's class to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should multiple users be able to store different state machine on the same object? What if one defines a state that doesn't exist in the other?

Comment: Say, there is an object called Order. For customer1 the order states will be like Open -> Hold and Open -> Pending  and Pending -> Closed
For customer2 it will be like Open -> In Progress, Open -> Hold and In Progress -> to Closed. When customer 1 logs in the transition should be the first one and when customer2 logs in it has to be the second flow